# Running a jQuery script (lightbox 2) within a Prototype/Scriptaculous environment

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, prototypejs, lightbox

I am trying to run a jQuery lightbox (lightbox 2) within a Magento Go store, which runs on the prototype/scriptaculous.

I have successfully added and run jQuery scripts that needs "activation" (for lack of a better terminology) such as the orbit slider by replacing $ with jQuery such as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(window).load(function() {
     jQuery('#featured').orbit();
 });
</script>
```

My understanding is that when orbit's js are executed it will 'know' to use jQuery as it was called that way.

However, the Lightbox 2 does not require "activation" in that way. All I needed to do is to load the js file and include the css file.

```
<script src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
<link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

and the script will supposedly pick up all links with the rel='lightbox'.

I cannot get it to work properly so my gut feeling tells me that it is conflicting with other libraries?

Question is -- How do I load the js in such a way that it will run in jQuery.noconflict mode?

Thanks in advance. 
Ryan

ps- lightbox.js 
https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/blob/master/js/lightbox.js

Answer (score 0):

In lightbox.js, try replacing line 43:

```
(function() {
```

with:

```
(function($) {
```

And then replace the line 351 (last):

```
}).call(this);
```

with this:

```
}).call(this, jQuery);
```

Not sure :/

Comment: Didn't work, unfortunately. Must be some other conflicts somewhere.

Comment: Did you also called jQuery.noConflict() after including jquery.js?

Answer (score 0):

try something along this example.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

    $(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#featured').orbit({
            interval: 4500  
        })
    }); 
</script>
```